# Typescript : An error occurs when reading and nesting an interface that contains a union value

Tags: typescript

**Question**

I nested an interface that contained a value of type union to manage many settings in separate files.

There is no problem when initializing the value to const, but there is a problem reading the value.

```
TS2339: Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'Grid | Waterfall'.
Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'Waterfall'.
```

Is there a way to avoid errors?
I have just started type scripts, so in such a situation I do not know how to solve Typescript.
Please help me know someone

**TypeScript Version**: 2.6.1

**Code**

```
interface Grid {
  rows: number;
  columns: number;
}
interface Waterfall {
  moreButton: boolean;
  forceSquare: boolean;
}
interface View {
  viewType: Grid | Waterfall;
  postType: string;
  mainColor: string;
}
const view: View = {
  viewType: {
    rows: 3,
    columns: 5
  },
  postType: 'image, video',
  mainColor: 'blue',
};

console.log(view.viewType.rows);
```

Comment: It kinda defeats the purpose of static typing if your `viewType` can either have rows and columns or moreButton and forceSquare. I think the problem is how you want to use `viewType: Grid | Waterfall;` It should be one or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning is a good one; it's telling you that `view.viewType.rows` might not exist.  You have to convince the compiler that it does exist before it will let you use it.  Here's one way:

```
if ('rows' in view.viewType) {
  // view.viewType is now known to be Grid
  console.log(view.viewType.rows); // okay
  console.log(view.viewType.columns); // also works
}
```

Does that make sense?  Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, thank you
I found the answer somewhere that it would work if I wrote something like `if (view.viewType.rows)`. But it did not work.
But your answer works well.